# Progress bar isn't working

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm trying to use 4 progress bars in a 4 step process. Essentially the progress bars are being used because the project takes a LONG time to run, using a single progress bar with the (divide by ten) that normally is used would mean that the progress bar would gain 1 sliver every 20 minutes. (too long.)

Here is the code:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(a++);

if (a == 100)
{
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(b++);
    a = 0;
}

if (b == 100)
{
    backgroundWorker3.ReportProgress(c++);
    b = 0;
}

if (c == 100)
{
    c = 0;
    d = 25;
}

backgroundWorker4.ReportProgress(d);
```

The problem is, the first progress bar goes to about 99% and stops, the 2nd bar doesn't move at all but the process is still running.

Comment: Have you tried ++a instead of a++ (subsequently the same for b & c)?  Also, what happens with D - is it just left at 25% until completion?

Comment: Are the `ProgressChanged` events firing?  Are you really firing events for four different `BackgroundWorker`s from this code?  Is this code running in one, or all, of the `BackgroundWorker`s?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do parameter increment before passing to method. In C# [increment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) can appear before and after its operand. When you do (a++) it is postfix increment operation. Result of this operation is value of a *before* it was incremented. Thus maximum value passed to `ReportProgess` will be 99 instead of 100. If you change increment operation to (++a), which is prefix increment, then result of operation will be value of a *after* increment:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(++a);
```

Same with other calls. Btw last reporting is strange - value of `d` changed only once. Maybe you should use `d += 25` instead?

Comment: It's not the full code, it's just part of it. I'll try this and see if it fixes.

Comment: Well that fixed the first bar, but the other bars still won't increase.